# Using root Commands with JSch (ssh)

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I can run regular commands like rm /home/user/Desktop/file but when i cannot run root commands.

My intent is to configure a squid service running commands like:
apt-get install squid
service squid start
service

but those commands require superuser authentication.

Does anyone knows how to fix it? Thanks

```
public void executarComandoSsh(Session session, String comando) {
    try {
        ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setPty(true);
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setPtyType("vt100");
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setXForwarding(true);
        System.out.println("Comando " + comando);
        channel.setCommand(comando);
        channel.setInputStream(null);
        channel.setErrStream(System.err);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(channel.getInputStream()));

        channel.connect();
        String line = "";

        while (true) {
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("-- " + line);
            }
            break;
        }
        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();

    } catch (JSchException | IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ServidorNegocioImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are "root commands"? What specific problem are you having? Any error message? OR what does not work? What did you try to execute the "root commands"?

Comment: sry.. I just added those root commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved..

i edited the /etc/sshd/sshd_config and set enable root login: yes...